# Finding out the shape of the body from blackbody radiation spectrum

Tags: mathematical-physics

I have an idea similar to this, but I thought looking for an answer on this question might be a good start.

Would it be possible to configure the geometry, i.e. shape of the body when we know the blackbody radiation spectrum for any given angle?

I heard something similar to that it was proposed by Hilbert to Herman Weyl, but I could not really find the source.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: ["In addition, a black body is a diffuse emitter (its emission is independent of direction)."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation#Black_body)

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can! The tungsten wire in the old fashioned light bulb is a black body emitter. When it is hot you can see its shape. Most of the time we look at light scattered from or transmitted by, not emitted from, objects. This indeed gives much more detailed information than emission.